# How to change textbox background color whenever error occurs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I get an email id in a text box.So whenever i enter the wrong formatted email then the text box's background color should change.

This is my code for jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $(':text').hover(function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor="black"},
        function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"});
});
```

This is my html code :

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter email" ng-blur="visitedEmail = true" name="email" />
    <p class="error" ng-show="myform.email.$invalid && !myform.email.$pristine &&visitedEmail">Invalid email!</p>
</div>
```

In the above code i have used ng-blur so when i lost focus the action has to be done.
Now i need to change the text box's background color when i lost focus(case of wrong email format).

Whats wrong with my code and give some tips to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    <div>
        <input id="EmailTextBox" type="text" placeholder="enter email" name="email" onblur="ValidateEmail();" />
    </div>
    <script>
        function ValidateEmail()
        {
        var emailTextBox = document.getElementById("EmailTextBox");
        if(//checksForValidity
           emailTextBox.value != "")
            return true;
        else
            emailTextBox.style.backgroundColor = "black";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the ng-class directive to achieve this.

What it does is apply/remove css classes based on a condition.  So you want the red-background css class to show under the error condition.

It should look something like this:

Markup:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter email" ng-blur="visitedEmail = true" 
name="email" ng-class="{red-background: myform.email.$invalid && 
!myform.email.$pristine && visitedEmail }"
```

CSS:

```
.red-background {
  background: red;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="text"
ng-blur="visitedEmail = true" required ng-pattern="pattern" ng-class="{red-background: myform.email.$invalid && 
!myform.email.$pristine && visitedEmail }">...I tried with this but it doesn't work

Comment: it works fine but after i change the css class name from ".red-background" to ".red" only..I dont know but the "-" not works in ng-class..thank you